# How to add a button to the variable hover popup

Tags: java, eclipse, sdk, eclipse-plugin

Is it possible to add a button to the popup/tooltip that appears when you hover over variables and other content in the Eclipse editor? I have searched for a while and haven't found any examples of someone doing this.

To be more clear, when you hover over a variable or type in the Editor, then click inside the popup, the window below appears, with some buttons at the bottom, such as "Show in Javadoc View" and "Go to Declaration".

[image]

I would like to add another button to this bottom toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be any way to change this tool bar.

The Javadoc hover code is `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover`. The tool bar is created in the `doCreateInformationControl` method and the contents are hard coded there.